# "English origin person" vs. "Person of English origin"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, attributive-nouns

Is it correct to say:

> He is an English origin person

Rather than:

> He is a person of English origin

I am looking for a short way to differentiate between persons of English origin, as opposed to immigrants or their descendants. I can't use English born because descendants are also English born.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"English origin person" sounds awkward to a native speaker. "Person of English origin" is better but still clunky, and also sounds more like something you would say of an emigrant - as in, Rupert lives in Australia, but he is of English origin.

If you want to specify people of English ancestry and heritage, one option I've heard is [anglo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anglo):

> An English person or person of English ancestry.

Since that can have multiple meanings, however (here in Canada, an anglo is an [anglophone](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Anglophone#English) regardless of background), you could get more specific and say [Anglo-Saxon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxon):

> A person of English ethnic descent.

Comment: Note that Anglo-Saxon excludes Welsh, Scottish, and Cornish people, who are in no way immigrants to the United Kingdom. So I don't think this is the word the OP is looking for.

Comment: @PeterShor I suppose it depends on whether the asker does want to single out "English" as opposed to "United Kingdom". I'm not positive there is a non-historically-fraught blanket term for all those; regardless, I removed the reference to immigration.